# Honeycomb app works in Emulator and locally but does not work when I create the signed APK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-3.0-honeycomb

When I debug directly from Eclipse in the emulator/tablet, my app works fine. But when I try to sign it and download it from android market after putting it there, it does not seem to work and throws

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.prakashkut.HackerNews.NewsListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:500)
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:468)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
```

I tried putting a empty constructor too.

Am I missing something really simple ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I tried to create the signed APK on another machine and it worked fine. 
I guess there was some problem in the way Eclipse signed the APK the first time around because when even when I used jarsigner to sign it manually, it worked fine.